# HDD manager software

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, cmd.exe

I have noticed my HDD turns on too often, even when i'm not directly using it (like opening windows explorer, or task manager). Is there a software that can force shutdown HDD until ordered otherwise? It can also be cmd command to be honest. I know that google exists, but all links lead to partition manager.

Comment: What is the real issue here? “I have noticed my HDD turns on too often, even when i'm not directly using it.” This is 100% normal. Memory is swapped to the disk regularly for tasks that are open yet not being used right at the moment. Additionally lots of processes exist on modern OS’ that do things like index files and even optimize space. All of these things are needed parts of the OS. So what problems are you noticing or are you simply hearing a drive work and assume it is bad? Because modern drives won’t die from use like that and you won’t extend life by disabling core OS functions.

Comment: I would rephrase this to include a more concrete question. As it stands now this is just asking for software suggestions (which is not allowed on this site).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Frame challenge.*

If the OS wants to check a known-connected drive for any reason whatsoever, if the drive won't spin up on request then the OS will hang until it does.

This is probably not a good idea.

Comment: I downvoted because it is clear this should have been a comment since it’s really just another question posed for the original poster.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 … which is precisely why I headed it as a frame challenge. Even if possible, this will not produce desired results. personally I don't like answers as comments [even if I do it myself]. It claims 'i'm too important to be included in the voting process, therefore you should read me before any actual answer" Hence.. I posted as an answer.\

Comment: I can't see why OS would want to check out non-OS drive, but i'm not OS master. Of course bots (also known as moderators) closed the topic, but i'm marking your response as solution.

Comment: It was closed because it is a request for a product. That's off-topic. i thought I might just get in my frame challenge before it closed… just made it ;-)

Comment: @Jave2 Also, I am not a moderator. I simply have high rep. You can gain high rep too by posting questions and answers that gain up votes. This question was justifiably closed not just because it was a software recommendation question, but it also seems like you are not being clear about what the issue is. In my experience when someone asks a question like what you are asking it shows a desire by someone to squeeze more life out of a hard drive by doing things that don’t really do much. If you are truly concerned, upgrade to an SSD drive. Will speed up your system and no worries about noise.